# How to prevent one particular process from hogging the semaphore all the time

Tags: c, fork, semaphore

So I have a shared memory and this shared memory is accessed by master and user processes. The master starts off and forks off user processes (followed by exec). All the processes need to communicate with each other. This is what is supposed to happen:

```
user process n gets semaphore write some msg in shared memory 
master process gets semaphore reads this msg does something
user process n gets semaphore writes some msg in shared memory 
master process gets semaphore reads this msg does something
```

What is instead happening is:

```
user process 1 writes something in shared msg 
user process 2 gets semaphore 
user process 3 gets sempahore but msg is meant for master (There is a bit in shared memory which will not allow the user processes to read messages meant for master)
master process gets semaphore reads msg does something, empties shared msg
master process gets semaphore, nothing in shared msg
master process gets semaphore,nothing in shared msg
```

So basically the master and user processes should be alternating but somehow the alternation is very less and most of the time when oss or user process sem_posts the semaphore it takes it back immediately.

Does anyone have any better way to do this?
I was thinking of using msg_send and msg_receive instead os semaphore but honestly I'm so far off in this project and it would take me a ton loads of work to change everything.

Is there any way to make sure the semaphore is taken only by a particular PID?

Comment: Why do you think it should alternate? Perhaps use `yeild`

Comment: First, why is it a problem?  If the processing is supposed to alternate like that, you need to design your synchronization object usage to implement such a pattern.  In general, any code waiting for the same object will be waiting in order to do the same thing, and you don't really care which thread of execution actually does it.  You can't use one semaphore, for example, to get two threads to do two different things.  Well, maybe you can, but it's a lot harder than just using two semaphores.

Comment: Everything is done in 1 thread. In short I am not using threads at all. The reason it should alternate is the program moves further only once oss reads a shared msg from user process. is oss grabs the semaphore and releases and grabs again the porgram won't move further. same with user process.